# Find correlation between names and score

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, excel

I'm new to data mining and hope you can help me with my task :)

First some details about my (input data)

I've got an excel table with the following structure:

```
document_id, name_0, name_1, name_n, score
       1234,       0,     0,      1,  50.1
       1235,       1,     1,      1,  70.9
       1236,       0,     0,      0,  20.5
```

The `id` is a unique number, the name columns explain if the `name_i` occurs in the data (1) or not (0) (the label of the column is the name of the person) and the corresponding score of the document. As you can see the excel file looks like a vector.

My goal is to find a (existing/not existing) correlation between names (nominal attribute) and a score (numeric attribute). So if the score of the document is potentially higher if name_0 or name_1 (or name_i) occurs in the document.

First I thought about a correlation matrix but I'm not sure if it is the right tool to work on with this task because correlation means for me "if x gets higher than y gets higher/lower" and the attribute "name" can't get higher or lower. Even then, I'm not sure how to interpret the results to prove or dismiss the existing/not existing correlation.

Do you have any clue if there are any practices to handle this task correctly?

Comment: Maybe start with a logistic regression for `name_i` with predictor score, one regression for each of the `name_` variables?